# Empty a char device from java at application start

Tags: java, file-io, nonblocking

my application reads from a char device, which is filled from kernel space. Currently I'm accessing it with a RandomAccessFile which is working fine.

My Problem is, before I start my application, data is already written to the char device.
(There is constant data at a minimum of 1 per second)

So, I want to "ignore" the data which was inserted before I started my application.

The problem is, I cannot tell, how much data is currently in this char device. It is like reading from a pipe, I tried some Reader classes but accessing the lenght always thorws an Illegal seek Exception.

I think there is a way to literally "empty up" the char device before I start reading data from it, maybe someone can point me in the right direction.
I never worked with non blocking io, like the java.nio. stuff, is this the way to go?

Unfortunatly if have no code ready for posting, if you need some, let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I found no beautiful way to solve that problem.

The only solution I found is  skipping it manually checking System.nanoTime
(Scala Code!):

```
var run = true
val test = new Array[Byte](10000); //<- needs to be that big!
var count = 0;
device = new RandomAccessFile("/dev/mydevice", "r")
while (run) {
  val time = System.nanoTime();
  device.read(test)
  count = count +1
  if ((System.nanoTime() - time)>100000000) {
    run = false
  }
}
device.close
println("Skipped ["+count+"] lines")
```

If anyone can bring up a better solution, I appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

i assume you already tried `RandomAccessFile.setLength(0)` (although i doubt that will work, that's not really how pipes are used)?  What about using a FileInputStream and calling skip() until you can't skip any further?

Comment: Hi, no I didnt try that. As I read in the documentation of setLength, it tries to access length. Whenever length is accessed, I get an Illegal seek Exception. I tried using FileInputStream, but ran into the same problems with this Illegal Seek. I check if skip works for me.

Comment: Hi again, neither setLength nor skip works. I get always Illegal seek IOException.